# Ansible - how to 'loop' an ansible task in case it fails?

Tags: automation, ansible

I have a problem with Ansible playbook, specifically one of it's task. The task looks like this:

```
- name: Start Integration Server
  script: "{{ instDir_path }}start_All.sh"
- name: Wait for Integration Server to start
  wait_for:
    port: 5515
    delay: 10
```

What it does is running `start_All.sh`, which is a simple script that is actually starting two servers. The server number one is starting fast and fine every single time. The second one has sometimes a problem to start within the 300 second default delay of anslibles `wait_for`. I don't want to change the default value, instead, I would like to have something like this:

IF SERVER STARTED - finish and go to the next playbook
IF SERVER FAILED TO START - run the `stop_All.sh` to shut down the first server correctly, then re-run the `start_All.sh` again and repeat the `wait_for` procedure again, and again until the server is started correctly. Or maybe not again and again - but it has to try to start the server at least 3 times.

Is that even possible in Ansible?
This

Comment: Ansible is meant to be as declarative as possible. Why not implement all this crutches inside start_All.sh?

Answer (score 0):

IntegrationServer (SoftwareAG I guess) should have lock file created during running. Therefore maybe you can try:

```
# wait until the lock file is present
- wait_for:
    path: /var/lock/file.lock
    state: present
```

From ansible documentation:

> When checking for a file or a search string present or started will
>   ensure that the file or string is present before continuing, absent
>   will check that file is absent or removed